# internet explorer on windows 10 loads css twice when css contains 'body { ... }' rule

Tags: html, internet-explorer

unfortunately have to make it work in IE (if possible).

problem: IE loads css twice when css contains `body { ... }` rule.

i have a simple html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test body-reset</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
</head>
<body>
hello
</body>
</html>
```

**test.css**

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

**result in ie on windows10**
[image]

**question**

i see that the second request taken from cache, but in real world i have
large angular-generated css secured by super-domain cookie `.domain.com` and for the second request IE is not sending this cookie - so request is different and cache is not working.

as a fast solution i'm unsecuring css - then the second request is coming from cache.

is there any solution to disable the second css request from IE ?

Comment: Googling around, double-loading CSS files seems to go as far back as IE7! Info at one site claims: `Recommended ways to get around this problem is to use an absolute, root relative or location relative path to your CSS files`. No IE on my phone, so I can't test that theory.

Comment: thanks for answering. i tried different kind of paths for css - no difference still 2 requests.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in my IE 11.630.19041.0 on win10. Which version of IE are you using? I suggest that you can clear IE cache, then check **Always refresh from server** icon and **Clear entries on navigate** icon, then try again: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqHkQ.png.

Comment: good point. for some reason i have not the latest IE. going to update IE and revalidate. thank you!

Comment: No problem! You can come back if you make any progress.